# How do I add sector angles to a pie chart using JSXGraph?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I'm using JSXgraph to draw pie charts, and I need to mark on the size of the angle of each sector at the center, like this:

[example pie chart with angles at center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSGS7.png)

The code below is taken from https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Pie_chart, but I can't find anything in the docs about how to add angles to the chart. Is this possible?

```
var dataArr = [30,16,14,10,10,8,6,6];
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {showNavigation:false, showCopyright:true, boundingbox: [-2.4, 8, 13.6, -4]});
board.containerObj.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
board.options.label.strokeColor = 'yellow';
board.suspendUpdate();

var a = board.createElement('chart', dataArr, 
    {chartStyle:'pie',  
     colors:['#0F408D','#6F1B75','#CA147A','#DA2228','#E8801B','#FCF302','#8DC922','#15993C','#87CCEE','#0092CE'],
     fillOpacity:0.8, center:[5,2], strokeColor:'black', highlightStrokeColor:'black', strokeWidth:4,
     labels:['War games','Sport games', 'Old games','Strategy games', '3D games', 'Puzzle games','Board games', 'I do not play games'],
     highlightColors:['#E46F6A','#F9DF82','#F7FA7B','#B0D990','#69BF8E','#BDDDE4','#92C2DF','#637CB0','#AB91BC','#EB8EBF'],
     highlightOnSector:true, 
     highlightBySize:true,
     gradient:'linear'
    }
);
board.unsuspendUpdate();
```

Comment: Do you want to add the angle values in degrees as texts in the construction or do you want to supply the numerical value of the angles for each "piece of the pie"?

Comment: Thanks Alfred - I want the angles in degrees as texts in the construction, as in the diagram linked to in the question.